# Html Checkbox when clicked not changing the attribute

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have a small html table where one column consists of a checkbox and another one some caption. Based on the table data i need to generate a XML file. Everything is working fine, but when i change the checkbox value to true or false by clicking its not reflecting in the xml file i generate. the checked attribute seems to be fixed by default. here is my code. please help me where I am wrong. thanks in advance..

```js
function createxml() {

    var table = $("#fruitsTable tbody");

    var detxml = '';

    detxml += '<ROOT>';
    detxml += '<Data>';

    var cRow = 1;

    table.find('tr').each(function (i) {   
        detxml += '<Report_Details ';                        
        detxml += 'FruitName="'       + $(this).find('td').eq(1).text() + '" ';

        var chkval = $(this).find('td').eq(0).html();

        if ($(chkval).prop('checked') == true)
            {
                detxml += 'Visible="1"';
            }
        else
            {
                detxml += 'Visible="0"';
            }
        detxml += 'DOrder="'        + cRow + '" ';                        
        detxml += '>';
        detxml += '</Report_Details>';   

        cRow++;                     
    });

    detxml += '</Data>';
    detxml += '</ROOT>';
    alert (detxml);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="fruitsTable">
   <tbody>
     <tr> 
       <td> <input type="checkbox" checked> </input>   </td>     
       <td> Apple </td>      
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td> <input type="checkbox" checked> </input>   </td>     
      <td> Orange </td>      
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td> <input type="checkbox"> </input>   </td>     
      <td> Pineapple </td>      
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td> <input type="checkbox"> </input>   </td>     
      <td> Grapes </td>      
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</br>
<button onclick="createxml()"> Show String </button>
```

Comment: You are using incorect syntax for input, do not provide closing tag, just `content <input type="checkbox" /> content`

Comment: i tried that too. its not working

Comment: The real super easy way to debug!, its do go line by line and to write console.log messages, this way you can determine where you are wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to wrong val of `chkval`.

It should be:

```
 var chkval = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
```

You were using `.html()`

> The html() method sets or returns the content (innerHTML) of the selected elements.

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/wh02xmvj/1/)

```js
function createxml() {

  var table = $("#fruitsTable tbody");

  var detxml = '';

  detxml += '<ROOT>';
  detxml += '<Data>';

  var cRow = 1;

  table.find('tr').each(function(i) {
    detxml += '<Report_Details ';
    detxml += 'FruitName="' + $(this).find('td').eq(1).text() + '" ';

    var chkval = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    if ($(chkval).is(":checked")) {
      detxml += 'Visible="1"';
    } else {
      detxml += 'Visible="0"';
    }
    detxml += 'DOrder="' + cRow + '" ';
    detxml += '>';
    detxml += '</Report_Details>';

    cRow++;
  });

  detxml += '</Data>';
  detxml += '</ROOT>';

  alert(detxml);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table id="fruitsTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox"> </input>
        </td>
        <td> Apple </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox"> </input>
        </td>
        <td> Orange </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox"> </input>
        </td>
        <td> Pineapple </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox"> </input>
        </td>
        <td> Grapes </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </br>
  <button onclick="createxml()"> Show String </button>

</body>
```

Comment: @srinivasan If the answer is correct can you mark this as correct